# What is a word for "someone who doesn't share the same enthusiasm"

Tags: single-word-requests

The other day I was trying to think of a describing word for "someone who doesn't share the same enthusiasm"

Example usage:

"After getting an A in my exam, I danced around my ______ classmate. He got a D."

I'm looking for the describing word for that classmate who did not share the same enthusiasm.

Edit: The above is admittedly a poor example. Here is another attempt:

> My wife and I took a "which dog are you" quiz. After getting 'pit bull', I began shadow boxing around my ___ wife. She had just gotten 'poodle'.

Comment: Did you look for an antonym for 'enthusiasm' in a thesaurus? 'apathetic' seems to be an antonym but is misleading in this context. Also, does it have to be on the same dimension as enthusiasm... maybe 'dejected' would work

Comment: Fair question. Poor example.

Comment: I did think of 'unenthusiased', but it's not a word. Now I realize the opposite of enthused is what I'm looking for. Is unenthused a word?

Comment: If you're gloating like that, I think your classmate would be _annoyed_.

Comment: Your question and both examples seem to involve two people reacting to TWO different (their respective) results, so the following wouldn’t really apply, but if two people were reacting to the SAME result (from their respective points of view), then “unimpressed” might work:  “I danced enthusiastically around my unimpressed father waving my straight-C Report Card in his [unimpressed] face,” for example. As posed, however, the accepted answer (or maybe even 'unenthusiastic') seems good to me, too.

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks for that note. I actually wrote "unimpressed", but have been itching for another word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an Oxford [entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unenthused):

> **unenthused** (*adj.*)
>   not interested or appreciative

You appreciate your exam grade, but he doesn't.

Comment: ... or 'unenthusiastic' which sounds more natural to me.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate that an answer has been selected, but just to add an option for others, I would suggest ***[indifferent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indifferent)***. (M-W)

Answer (score 2):

[Aloof](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aloof) - adjective - Conspicuously uninvolved and uninterested, typically through distaste.

Answer (score 1):

**unimpressed**  is the cool word. Oxford Concise

> ppl. a. 2.  Not affected by feelings of respect or awe.   1862